# Different Redirect_To in a Destroy action within a Controller Depending on Origin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a destroy function in a controller that works well, but the issue is that I need to redirect the user to different urls after deleting depending on where that button was clicked.

For example, if **user** access is seeing a list of **his** records from **index**, and clicks delete he is redirected back to index (I cannot use the :back action because it causes ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) via redirect_to index_path and if the user clicks the delete button from the "see all records" page I need the user to be redirected to see_all_records_path.

Do I need to create a different controller, action, etc? Let me know. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can check `request.referer` in your controller and redirect based on that value, it will have full URL of the page where they were when delete button was clicked. You can use regex or other ways to determine where you should redirect this user.

```
if request.referer.include?('see_all_records')
  ..redirect to see_all_records
else
  ..redirect to index
end
```

Comment: First, thank you for replying!

`def destroy
    @records = Records.find(params[:id])
     if @records.present?
       @records.destroy 
           if request.referer.contains?('profile')
             redirect_to user_path
           elsif request.referer.contains?('records')
             redirect_to see_all_records_path
           end
      else
       redirect_to error_page_path
     end
  end`

Gives me error undefined method `contains?'

Comment: sorry my bad, include? is what you should be using, answer updated.